# liking/disliking people or choosing friends. Freedom of ....?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I want to tell my old brother that he should give the freedom for his son to <strike>be friends with,</strike> like or dislike, whoever he wants to.

What freedom is that? Is there one word/expression that I could use.

I asked one of my friends and he said you could say: **Freedom of amity and enmity**

I Like it a lot, is there a better expression?
It doesn't have to be commonly used, as long as it is correct and has a nice ring.

Edit: I'm looking for an expression that is appropriate for freedom of liking whoever he wants. - not only being friends with whoever he wants.

Comment: "Freedom of amity and enmity" is a great phrase.  I think you'll have trouble doing better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Freedom of association.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_association)

Comment: Does this work for liking and disliking people? I'm want to emphasize on this part.

Comment: This is the freedom to hang out with (or not hang out with) whoever you want. I don't know if it quite works for liking and disliking people, but that's something nobody can force you to do in any case.

Comment: @Peter: you're right, nobody can force you, but some people might not like it (who you like/dislike). I'm trying to find a response to those people.

Comment: Freedom of favor?

Answer (score 1):

Freedom of [befriendment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/befriendment)?  Oh, it wavy-lined me.  I stand by it.

> : the act of befriending

Comment: This works for friends, but not really for liking, disliking people. Nice though. Thanks

Comment: Besides possibly being one-sided (per RZ's comment) "freedom of befriendment" is clumsy to say.  "Freedom of friendship" is far less clumsy and can, like "freedom of association", be interpreted as freedom to choose or unchoose people as friends.